# Printing numbers sequentially using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sequence

I am trying to create multiple threads which print numbers one by one sequentially.

What I have tried to do is assign each thread a value and print only when the

`counter % (no of threads) == value of that thread else the thread waits`

When I tried this with 2 threads, I was able to achieve the result but the program is not running correctly for 3 threads.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        printer p1 = new printer(l,0);
        printer p2 = new printer(l,1);
        printer p3 = new printer(l,2);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(p3);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
    static Object l = new Object();
    static int c = 0;
}
class printer implements Runnable{
    Object lock;
    static int i = 0;
    int j;
    printer(Object lock,int j){
        this.lock = lock;
        this.j=j;
    }
    public void run(){

        synchronized(lock){
            try{
                while(i<1000){
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" starting to check with j="+j+ " i="+i);

                        if(i%3!=j){
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" not the one so waiting");
                            lock.wait();
                        }

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" i="+i);
                        i++;

                        lock.notifyAll();

                }

            }catch(InterruptedException ex ){

            }


        }


    }
}
```

Here is the output for the program :

```
Thread-0 starting to check with j=0 i=0
Thread-0 i=0
Thread-0 starting to check with j=0 i=1
Thread-0 not the one so waiting
Thread-1 starting to check with j=1 i=1
Thread-1 i=1
Thread-1 starting to check with j=1 i=2
Thread-1 not the one so waiting
Thread-0 i=2
Thread-0 starting to check with j=0 i=3
Thread-0 i=3
Thread-0 starting to check with j=0 i=4
Thread-0 not the one so waiting
Thread-1 i=4
Thread-1 starting to check with j=1 i=5
Thread-1 not the one so waiting
Thread-0 i=5
```

What I don't understand is that how is `Thread-0 i=2` getting printed by thread-0 without it going through check.( No print statement for Thread-0 checking its value) 
I was expecting Thread-2 to start here but instead, Thread-0 started running. Moreover, Thread-0 also didn't perform any check and straight away printed the value of i.

**My objective is to understand why this is not working as desired and why the code is behaving this way.**

Please don't provide me other code snippets that achieves the desired result.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible example for anything other than an academic exercise.  Normally you want to run threads asynchronous and as fast as possible, and that means problems that require small steps that must go in a particular order aren't well suited for multi-threading solutions.  This would probably run faster as a single thread.

Comment: True, I am not trying to achieve any real-life objective by this program, but rather help me understand why it's behaving this way.

Comment: That's fine, and academic exercises are a good way to learn.  I just wanted to point out that in real life you would have to think very hard about implementing anything like this as multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is this:

Some thread starts and finds it is not the one, so it waits:

```
if(i%3!=j){
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" not the one so waiting");
  lock.wait();
}
```

Then another thread finds it is the one, prints and increments, and then `notifyAll()` threads.  So what does that thread above do?  It just keeps executing.

```
if(i%3!=j){
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" not the one so waiting");
  lock.wait();
}
// just keeps going...
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" i="+i);
i++;
```

Programs execute in order.  The only thing your program can do after that one check is to move to the next print statement.  There's nothing else that the code does.

The standard way of checking and waiting is to use a `while` loop so you don't drop out of the `while` until your check succeeds.

```
while(i%3!=j){
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" not the one so waiting");
  lock.wait();
}
```

Not tested, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using a while loop did solve the issue.    So the issue was because of not continously checking if the thread is the one to print the value.